# Run long Oracle stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I run from PHP using:

```
//Request does not change
$sql = 'BEGIN SP_GET_MY_DATA(:POP, :SEG, :DUR, :VIEW, :PAGE, :OUTPUT_CUR); END;';            

//Statement does not change
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);                     
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':POP',$pop);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':SEG',$seg);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':DUR',$dur);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':VIEW',$view);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':PAGE',$page);    

//But BEFORE statement, Create your cursor
$cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn)

// On your code add the latest parameter to bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":OUTPUT_CUR", $cursor,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);

// Execute the statement as in your first try
oci_execute($stmt);

// and now, execute the cursor
oci_execute($cursor);

// Use OCIFetchinto in the same way as you would with SELECT
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($cursor, OCI_RETURN_LOBS )) {
    print_r($data}
}
```

The problem is I have millions of rows and complex logic in stored procedure. When I execute SP_GET_MY_DATA through SQL developer, it takes around 2 hours to complete it.

PHP is timing out when I do it. I cannot increase the max_execution_time in PHP as well.

How can I run this on Oracle or using PHP without timing out? Please help.

Comment: Run it as a program with DBMS_SCHEDULER oracle package

Comment: @OldProgrammer - can you give me an example for the same?

Comment: No. google "oracle dbms_scheduler" and read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered how to use Oracle Scheduler to run a long running procedure asynchronously pretty comprehensively in this answer on the DBA stack exchange.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/67913/38772

TL;DR is

```
-- submit this as a background job
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
      job_name => 'MY_BACKGROUND_JOB'
    , job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'    
    , job_action => 'SP_GET_MY_DATA'
    , enabled => TRUE
    , auto_drop => TRUE
  );
END;
```

You'll have to do a little more work if you want to pass in parameters to the procedure.  You may find this answer helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42119/38772/

For additional reference with all the gory details, the relevant chapter from Oracle's documentation is at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm

Comment: this is great. However, if I want DBMS_Scheduler to run jobs sequentially, how can I do it? I don't want to overload my Oracle server because of many requests.

Comment: @dang, if you have several stored procedures you want to execute serially, you could write a new stored procedure which simply calls your other stored procs in sequence, basically what I would call a wrapper procedure.  Then you have the Scheduler job call that new procedure.

Comment: Joshua - ah, what I meant was - let's say there are 10 different stored procedures which I will call through PHP, and then 15 users access those 10 calls, so I will have 150 jobs created in DBMS_Scheduler. If I have 150 jobs, my Oracle server would go slow. What I was wondering was - can I run jobs sequentially? That is - instead of running all 150 jobs parallely, Oracle takes one job at a time, processes it and then takes the next one.

Comment: @dang, in that case, it sounds like you need a queue.  Oracle does have an Advanced Queue feature (AQ), but I've always found it to be somewhat complex.  It's tempting to use a DB table as a queue, but many people will warn you not to do this -- see http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/why-database-as-queue-so-bad.  This would be a pretty good case for using RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ as a queueing solution. You could even use PHP (or any language) to implement the queue worker.

Answer (score -2):

Don't increase max_execution_time, set it to 0, allow it to run indefinitely. If you are going to return loads of rows, make sure to either increase memory (ini_set) or allow immediate buffer flushing so that it can output directly to client.

The latter will also prevent clients from prematurely disconnecting because they didn't get any data. (`ob_implicit_flush(true);`)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but won't it cause memory issues?

Comment: If you implicit flush, then no. Output is immediately sent to the client instead of being kept in the output buffer (ie. output is sent before the script is fully finished), together with fetch_assoc it will actually be quite low in memory, however the client will receive all the rows so that might fill up a bit on the client side.